# Uploadify - IO Error with Cloudflare

Tags: uploadify

I'm using Uploadify to upload videos to my website and it is working fine. But my issues is Uploadify returning error, IO-Error when I'm using Cloudflare. Is there any way to use Uploadify with Cloudflare?

I really liked Cloudflare because I see some performance improvement and even they show a message when site is down.

Answer (score 0):

There probably isn't enough detail in the post to really help. Did you try [contacting us](https://support.cloudflare.com/home)?

Helpful things to know:
1. Are any CloudFlare error messages happening?
2. Where is this happening (admin back end, etc.).
3. Where that service is making their calls from (IP addresses).

Note: If you do know their IPs, try whitelisting them in your CloudFlare Threat Control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration of SSL it may happen, some upload scripts have problems with Self-signed certificates (in case you are using Full SSL configuration)